# How to put select query in a list in C#? I get an error

Tags: c#, postgresql, .net-core, razor-pages

I'm trying to make a webpage in c# .net core razorpages. Basically I want the values of a specific column from my postgresql table in a list, and then show these values in the select option in html. But I'm having some problems on the c# side. I get this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Project_Corona.Models.WorkspaceModel>' [Project_Corona]

Here is the code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Project_Corona.Database;
using Project_Corona.Models;
using Npgsql;

namespace Project_Corona.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        public IActionResult Employeepage()
        {

            var cs = Database.Database.Connector();

            using var con = new NpgsqlConnection(cs);
            con.Open();

            List<WorkspaceModel> res = new List<WorkspaceModel>();
            res = ("Select location FROM workspaces").ToList();
            return View();
        } 
      
    }
    

}
```

This is the code from WorkspaceModel.cs (if necessary)

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Project_Corona.Database;
using Project_Corona.Models;
using Npgsql;

namespace Project_Corona.Models
{
    public class WorkspaceModel
    {
        [BindProperty]
        public string LocationName { get; set; }
        [BindProperty]
        public string RoomName { get; set; } 
        [BindProperty]
        public int SquareMeters { get; set; } = 1;
        [BindProperty]
        public int Lengthws { get; set; } = 1;
        [BindProperty]
        public int Widthws { get; set; } = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: There's a whole tonne of learning that you really need to do before asking this question I'm afraid. I'd suggest you run through some tutorials first.

Comment: What is `("Select location FROM workspaces")` a placeholder for? Apparently it's not something that is a list of WorkspaceModel.

Comment: It's a sql language, i added postgresql package. This query should output the list of that specific column from the table 'workspaces'

Comment: You might think it's SQL, but it's actually just a string. Calling ToList on it gives you a List<char> of all the characters in the string.

Comment: @DavidG, i have ran through lots of tutorials but im still lost.. hope anyone can give me a solution. I dont know how to solve

Comment: You can start by trying to execute your SQL on your open connection. I think that's in a tutorial somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use [EntityFramework Core for PostgreSQL](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/) to query your database?

I created a small example [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5utOwK)

Simply create a `DbContext` with your database server settings:

```
public class WorkspaceContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<WorkspaceModel> Workspaces { get; set; }

    //protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder) => optionsBuilder.UseInMemoryDatabase("inmemory");
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder) => optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql("Host=my_host;Database=my_db;Username=my_user;Password=my_pw");
}
```

... and call `container.AddDbContext<WorkspaceContext>();` in your Dependency Injection configuration.

Now you can query your underlying database very easy by calling:

```
var res = ctx.Workspaces.Select(w => w.LocationName);
// var res = ctx.Workspaces.FromSqlRaw("Select location FROM workspaces");
```

Then you will get the result according to your sql statement: `Select location FROM workspaces`